# How do I build a single access web service?

Tags: java, weblogic, jersey, jax-rs

I have a Jax-RS Jersey web service on Weblogic. It runs fine but returns a large amount of data. The problem is if I have more that 4 calls for the service at the same time I use up all the JVM memory on the server, then everything stops working and I have to reboot.

How can I limit the service to only run 2 or 3 instances and have other calls wait?

Comment: Added `weblogic` tag, since solution can be (most probably) weblogic specific (like tuning connection pool).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you returning your data? Do you create the entire object to return in memory? If so then you may want to look into streaming the response instead.

Can you give us an idea as to what your service is doing?

Edit:
You can stream stuff (like data from a `ResultSet`) like this;

```
@GET
public MyResultStream getData()
{
  ResultSet rs = queryDatabase();
  return new MyResultStream(rs);
}
```

You'll need to provide MyResultStream yourself;

```
public class MyResultStream implements javax.ws.rs.core.StreamingOutput
{
  private ResultSet rs;

  public MyResultStream (ResultSet rs)
  {
    this.rs = rs;
  }

  public void write(OutputStream output)
  {
    //write any document pre-able
    // for example <results>

    while (rs.next())
    {
      //get the data from the ResultSet and write it to the output in XML form
      // for example <result><foo>bar</foo></result>
    }

    //write any document post-amble
    // for example </results>
  }
}
```

Remember you'll have to close your `ResultSet` somehow.

Comment: It reads db2 on a mainframe, loops through the resultset to load and object. Then the Jersey Jaxb converts it to XML and returns it.

Comment: I am building a list object from the resultset then returning the whole object.

Comment: I was letting the jersey framework use jaxb on my list object.

Answer (score 0):

If you are crashing the JVM with only three or four requests, then I would probably start looking at the architecture of what is done. As Qwerky mentioned, are you creating all the objects you are returning? Are those object heavy? Could you use lighter objects for returning the data? Do you have to return all the data at once? How much (number of records/object) data are you potentially returning? How big (size in KB, MB, etc)? Does the server have enough memory? Is the min and max memory of the server set on startup to values that help it perform better? Is there a leak? Am I creating too many objects on the heap too fast?

And pending it isn't something with the application in itself, what about clustering and load balancing (to spread out the requests).

Also...depending on the amount of data you are returning...sometimes a web service is NOT a good thing. At my company we had a case where we tried to develop a web service that needed to process send back around 30K rows of data. It was just to much to handle for it. We actually ended up turning that process into a batch process. The results of that process were then used by our web UI and web services. Since the users didn't need the data until the next day anyway it just made it easier to manage the processing of the data.

Just some differing thoughts to help give you some different angles to pursue this with.

Comment: I checked the logs and it is actually taking about 8 requests to kill the JVM. When it work it returns about 20MB of data, in about 3 seconds as XML.

Comment: Are you doing a lot of String concatentation using + (the plus sign)? We were doing that for some XML work in one of our server apps and almost killed the server due to that. We forgot Strings are immutable and it cost us heavily. If you are, I recommend switching to StringBuilder or StringBuffer. That could be where you get a lot of the heap generated from.

Comment: I am looping through the resultset to populate a row object, then I add the row to a list object and return the list object.

Comment: What is your min and max heap settings? Perhaps you are growing the heap too fast for initialization? What is the heap at right before it crashes?